# .Net aplication await time

Tags: azure, entity-framework, asp.net-core, profiling

I have an application written on .Net 6 and EF core 5.0.13 with MS SQL server. The application deployed on Azure and I noticed that sometimes the application is very slow on responses. After some investigations in the depth of Application Insight's Profiler, I found that most of the time, application spending on AWAIT_TIME.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Currently, I'm out of an idea where to dig. Can somebody suggest where to look, share some thoughts on it, or maybe somebody had the same issue?

Comment: the interesting thing is that it's not always about DB queries. Sometimes the application can spend 3 seconds just to convert http response into C# object. About queries, I didn't investigate specifically; I thought that ExecuteDatareaderAsync from the first image is the time spent on DB query

Comment: If you can share this part of the sample code, we can check whether there is a mix of asynchronous and synchronous methods.